# Finding the index of an item via its parent returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My understanding of jQuery is that these two lines of code should be functionally equivalent:

```
var firstIndex = ui.item.index();
console.log("firstIndex ", firstIndex);

var secondIndex = self.view.ui.childContainer.index(ui.item[0]);
console.log("secondIndex ", secondIndex);
```

Inspecting my DOM, I can clearly see that `ui.item[0].parentNode` is the same element as `self.view.ui.childContainer[0]`. As such, I would expect called index from the parent on the child to result in the same index as called index from the child. However, I get `-1` when called from the parent.

What am I misunderstanding?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here's a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2wE9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JQuery documentation:

> Description: Search for a given element from among the matched
>   elements.

So it searches not among the children.

If I understand correctly, that is what really intended to work in this case (for example):

html:

```
   <ul id='parent'>
        <li id='child-one'></li>
        <li id='child-two'></li>
        <li id='child-three'></li>
    </ul>
```

js:

```
   var firstIndex = $('#child-three').index();
    console.log("firstIndex ", firstIndex);

    var secondIndex = $("li").index($('#child-three'));
    console.log("secondIndex ", secondIndex);
```

Comment: Crap. You're right. Another SO post was incorrect. Doing $('#parent).children().index(...) works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should:

```
var secondIndex = self.view.ui.childContainer.index(ui.item[0]);
```

turn into:

```
var secondIndex = self.view.ui.childContainer[0].index(ui.item[0]);
```

Comment: jQuery provides the .index() method not the raw DOM element. If I de-reference my jQuery element and call index an error will be thrown.

Comment: Can you call it like this: $(self.view.ui.childContainer[0]).index(ui.item[0]);

Comment: I'm able to successfully call it with the code provided in the problem description. The issue is that it is returning -1 after calling index even though the element is a child of the parent.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Can you reproduce this in a fiddle.

Comment: I've updated the problem description with a JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, you are not telling your parent element to where to look for the indexes.

```
$('#parent').index($('#child-three')[0])
```

The above example work like this:

The `#child-three` element look for its siblings to find the index relative to `#parent`. So basically `#parent` has no sibling, so it returns `-1`

```
$('#child-three').index();
```

The above worked because `#child-three` has siblings `child-one` and `child-two`

[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/index/#entry-longdesc)

> The return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**

So to solve your problem you need:

```
$('#parent > div').index($('#child-three')[0]);
```

`#child-three` will try to find its siblings relative to `#parent` direct child `div` elements.